# Instaloader Scrape Results Lost On Computer?

Tags: web-scraping, download, instagram, file-location, instaloader

```
    >>> import instaloader  
    >>>
    >>> insta=instaloader.Instaloader()
    >>>
    >>> insta.login('myusername', 'mypassword')
    >>>
    >>> acc="targetprofile"
    >>>
    >>> insta.download_profile(acc,profile_pic_only=False)
```

I have been downloading full Instagram profiles from the command line no problem. The results are in the App data folder in folders names for the target profile. I used the above code from python, which looks like it worked, but I have no idea where the data went. Searching turns up nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the search wouldn't pull them up but it didn't.

Buried way deep in multiple layers in App Data in the Python folder itself.

Previously, results were in app data. This scrape result was placed directly in the python folder.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).